# Torch CTCCriterion error:Y ou must pass the size of each sequence in the batch as a tensor

Tags: deep-learning, lua, torch

I plan to implement CTC criterion in Torch for license plate recognizer. I go through the tutorial in [warp_ctc](https://github.com/baidu-research/warp-ctc/blob/master/torch_binding/TUTORIAL.md). However, during training, it failed, with the following error message:

```
/home/ubuntu/torch/install/bin/luajit: .../ubuntu/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nnx/CTCCriterion.lua:24: You must pass the size of each sequence in the batch as a tensor
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'assert'
        .../ubuntu/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nnx/CTCCriterion.lua:24: in function 'forward'
```

The ctc criterion receives 3 parameters, CTCCriterion:forward(output,label,sizes)

This is my target/label:

```
{
  1 : CudaTensor - size: 24
  2 : CudaTensor - size: 24
  3 : CudaTensor - size: 24
  4 : CudaTensor - size: 24
  5 : CudaTensor - size: 24
  6 : CudaTensor - size: 24
  7 : CudaTensor - size: 24
  8 : CudaTensor - size: 24
  9 : CudaTensor - size: 24
  10 : CudaTensor - size: 24
}
```

and output

```
{
  1 : CudaTensor - size: 24x36
  2 : CudaTensor - size: 24x36
  3 : CudaTensor - size: 24x36
  4 : CudaTensor - size: 24x36
  5 : CudaTensor - size: 24x36
  6 : CudaTensor - size: 24x36
  7 : CudaTensor - size: 24x36
  8 : CudaTensor - size: 24x36
  9 : CudaTensor - size: 24x36
  10 : CudaTensor - size: 24x36
}
```

Batchsize:24, I assume a length of maximum 10 characters for each and every complete license plate combination, 36 referring alphabet a-z,0-9.

I tried insert value 1, 24,36 , but same error message appear every round during training. I noticed that the datatype allowed in output and target were tensor type instead of table, so I tried converting and reshape, but it still doesn't help.